# error with code for unity 2d flip a enemy sprite (IA) code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to do a enemy IA chasing my character, i can do that, but when i want to code a script for the enemy sprite flip (Its a cube with 2 eyes) with a simple flip technique, the script doesnt work.

this is a little part of my code because a lot of then is for IA movement.

plz help

```
if (facingRight == false && moveInput > 0)
    {
        Flip();
    }
    else if (facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
    {
        Flip();
    }
}

private void Flip()
{
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
}
```

Comment: Please add more description. What do you expect and what happens instead?

Comment: try changing the "y" scale to -1 or even better if it is a sprite you can just say SpriteRenderer.flipX or SpriteRenderer.flipY.

Comment: You sure you didn't mean AI with IA ?

Answer (score 1):

Rotating your sprite is going to "flip" it, its going to well... rotate it.

The old fashioned way to flip a sprite was to set a negative scale, but that was a little counter intuitive so Unity helped us out by Adding [flipX](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-flipX.html). I have updated your code below.

```
if (facingRight == false && moveInput > 0)
    {
        Flip();
    }
    else if (facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
    {
        Flip();
    }
}

private void Flip()
{
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    GetComponet<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = facingRight;
}
```

Best of luck! :)